# ngix не раздает большие файлы(403 forbidden)

Tags: nginx

Nginx выдает видео файлы меньше 1Мб(примерно). На остальные выдает 403 ошибку. Я искал параметр который отвечает за выдачу файлов, но ничего не сработало. [image: Часть конфига]

Comment: Пробовали `proxy_max_temp_file_size`?

Comment: Вы уверены, что дело в размере, а не в правах доступа?

Comment: @andreymal я думаю так потому что маленькие видеофайлы отдаются без проблем

Comment: @mepihindeveloper не работает

Comment: @VladislavOliinyk а вы не «так думайте», а проверьте права доступа файлов командой `ls -l`

Comment: @andreymal проверил файлы проекта, все пренадлежит моему юзеру

Comment: Но nginx принадлежит не вам, и это может являться причиной ошибки доступа. Убедитесь, что чтение разрешено тому пользователю, от имени которого работает nginx

Comment: @andreymal Да, похоже действительно проблема была ошбике доступа. Как можно добавить права nginx?

Comment: Или добавьте пользователя, от имени которого запускается nginx, в группу, которой принадлежат файлы, или выдайте файлам право на чтение всеми подряд с помощью chmod

Comment: @andreymal когда я добавляю новые файлы в папку к которой доступ есть у всех, то на чтение этого файла права по умолчанию есть только у одного юзера? Как это исправить?

Comment: Без знания, кого куда откуда как вы добавляете, однозначно ответить на этот вопрос трудно